# Relationships in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to access a variable that i have done true a relationship in my model:

```
// Threads
public class Thread
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfMessages { get; set; }

    public int ViewCount { get; set; }

    public string[] Tags { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastEdited { get; set; }

    public int Vote { get; set; }

    // Other model relations
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public virtual ForumUser User { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to add a message to the database and also reference it in the list of messages

```
                thread.Group.Id = groupId;
```

It gave me a NULL reference exception. I do really now know how this works.

I'm going to show a other example that might explain a little bit more

```
`               // Saving the message in the database
                forumDb.Messages.Add(block);
                forumDb.Threads.Find(threadId).Messages.Add(block);
                forumDb.SaveChanges();
            }`
```

It would be nice if some one example what I'm doing wrong the model for that last example is the same

Comment: show how your retrieving "thread"

Comment: Where is the Group property new'ed ?  If Group is newer created thread.Group will try to set a property on a null reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information you gave, it looks like you didn't initialize the Group property of the Thread.

When creating an object, it's properties are not initialized. Since you try to access the id property of an uninitialized Group object, you get a null reference exception.

To solve your problem you could do this:

```
thread.Group = new Group(); // First initialize the group
thread.Group.Id = groupId;  // Set the id of the newly created Group object.
```

Comment: Okay i think you just gave me the answer but one more question that i also ment was now if i do that can i use thread.Group.(Any other propriety) and will that also work will it search the database for that value?

Comment: It really depends on what database technology you use and how you communicate with this database.
What are you using? SQL Server? And how are you connecting to this database?

Comment: Right now SQL LocalDB im just testing if it works. After that SQL 2016 . EF 6

Comment: EF should be able to store and retrieve nested objects such as Group in Thread

Comment: Yea I just tested it it works perfectly thanks so much still very new at EF